# How to "cut" address - mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I have question about mod_rewrite.

I have links like this

http://pagename.com/pl/meskie/longsleevy/criminal-squad#ad-image-0

And I want to "cut" everything after # to get

http://pagename.com/pl/meskie/longsleevy/criminal-squad

I have many products in my shop so I don't want to create many rules for every product.
So I created something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/pl/meskie/longsleevy/([[^#]+)#([^#]+)$ ^/pl/meskie/longsleevy/([[^#]+)$
```

But this is not working.
Can somebody help me?

My actual .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/extAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php

</IfModule>
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
RewriteRule ^/pl/meskie/longsleevy/([ˆ#]*)#.*$ /pl/meskie/longsleevy/$1
```

The brackets `()` on the left site will store everything before `#`, then print it with `$1` on the right side. Also `^` and `$` are useless on the right side.

Also, take care about the greedy `.*`

If you will change your mind and you want to rewrite url with fragment `#`, don't forget to add `[NE]` flag. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Further reading `apache docs`

Comment: It's not working. Maybe because javascript writes part after # dynamicly?

Comment: That shouldnt be problem. I edited my answer, try it. If it wont work, replace `#` with `\#`

Comment: That shows almost white page. Maybe something wrong with my .htaccess file (file was in the shop script). I edited my question with those lines.

Comment: yeah, try it without those conds and rules